# How to make a background scroll left

Tags: objective-c, sprite

I am making a game written in `Objective-C` and `SpriteKit` where the player can scroll the background either from the right to the left or from the left to the right.

Currently I have figured out how to write the code to make the background scroll right when the user swipes, but not how to make it scroll to the left.

So, my question is how do I make it scroll to the left? Here is the code:

`Sprites`:

```
  bg1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bg1"];
  bg1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
  bg1.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
  [self addChild:bg1];

  bg2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bg2"];
  bg2.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
  bg2.position = CGPointMake(bg1.size.width-1, 0);
  [self addChild:bg2];

//Update Method:

bg1.position = CGPointMake(bg1.position.x-4, bg1.position.y);
bg2.position = CGPointMake(bg2.position.x-4, bg2.position.y);

if (bg1.position.x < -bg1.size.width){
    bg1.position = CGPointMake(bg2.position.x + bg2.size.width,  bg1.position.y);
}

if (bg2.position.x < -bg2.size.width) {
    bg2.position = CGPointMake(bg1.position.x + bg1.size.width, bg2.position.y);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the current working code for scrolling to the right

Comment: The code under the update method comment is the code for scrolling to the right. I can't figure out what I have to change in that code to make it scroll left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 bg1.position = CGPointMake(bg1.position.x+4, bg1.position.y);
    bg2.position = CGPointMake(bg2.position.x+4, bg2.position.y);

if (bg1.position.x > bg1.size.width){
    bg1.position = CGPointMake(bg2.position.x - bg2.size.width,  bg1.position.y);
}

if (bg2.position.x > bg2.size.width) {
    bg2.position = CGPointMake(bg1.position.x - bg1.size.width, bg2.position.y);
}
```